# LESS mixin as function parameter

Tags: string, less, interpolation, mixins

..................................................

Existing mixins:

```
.mixin_1 {
    height: 1px;
}
.mixin_2 {
    height: 2px;
}
.mixin_3 {
    height: 3px;
}

.function(@get) {
  @get();
}
```

CALL:

```
.a{
  .function(mixin_1);
}
.b{
  .function(mixin_2);
}
.c{
  .function(mixin_3);
}
```

RESULT:

```
.a{
  height: 1px;
}
.b{
  height: 2px;
}
.c{
  height: 3px;
}
```

**Question:** how to do this? It's possible with current language specifications?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot currently do a dynamic call to a mixin based off a variable directly. You can make your `function()` mixin into a "caller" or "getter" mixin in which you register the mixins that can be called by your `function()` mixin, like so (which utilizes pattern matching):

**LESS**

```
.function(@get) {
  .-(@get); //call for mixin
  //register mixins you want to call with function
  .-(mixin_1) { .mixin_1; }
  .-(mixin_2) { .mixin_2; }
}

.mixin_1 {
    height: 1px;
}
.mixin_2 {
    height: 2px;
}

#block {
    .function(mixin_1);
}
```

**Outputs**

```
.mixin_1 {
  height: 1px;
}
.mixin_2 {
  height: 2px;
}
#block {
  height: 1px;
}
```

Of course, if you want the mixins invisible to the css, then change them to this:

**LESS change (added parenthesis)**

```
.mixin_1() {
    height: 1px;
}
.mixin_2() {
    height: 2px;
}
```

**New Output**

```
#block {
  height: 1px;
}
```

### Do you need it?

That level of abstraction can be useful at times, but often simply a pattern matching on the mixins will suffice. You would have to determine that. So with this simple example, it would be better to reduce to something like this:

```
.setHeight(1) {
    height: 1px;
}
.setHeight(2) {
    height: 2px;
}

#block {
    .setHeight(1);
}
```

More complex examples of mixins may not be so easily reduced, and then a mixin like what you want may be useful.

Comment: @FlamesoFF: That is not an operator at all (which is why you did not find it). It is a shorthand mixin name. Since hyphens are allowed in class/mixin names (like `.red-1`), this is just a way of doing a very short name. It works well in situations like this where you may need to repeat it often, and it is nested inside of another mixin. I actually picked up on that trick from another stack overflow contributor.

Comment: I guess the link to ["Pattern Matching"](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-parametric-feature-pattern-matching) won't harm.

Comment: Sorry, but not exactly. I edited my question to make it more detailed and understandable.

Comment: I understand your question. "Pattern Matching" feature is what @ScottS answer uses (e.g. my comment was in context of "what operator it is?")

Answer (score 0):

I think your code do same thing like this:

```
.mixin_1() {
    height: 1px;
}

.mixin_2() {
    height: 2px;
}

#block {
    .mixin_1();
}
```

And output will be:

```
#block {
  height: 1px;
}
```

I was asking about little different thing. However I found solution:

```
.function(@get) {
  .-(@get); //call for mixin
  //register mixins you want to call with function
  .-(mixin) { .mixin; }
}

#block {
    .mixin() {
        height: 1px;
    }
    .function(mixin);
}

#block {     
    .mixin() {
        height: 2px;
    }
    .function(mixin);
}
```

It outputs exactly what i wanted:

```
#block {
  height: 1px;
}
#block {
  height: 2px;
}
```

Overall, thanks for help.